# Check If Object Is Empty?

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I have an empty object, print_r returns the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
)
```

Using `if($object) {}` the code still runs, how can I check when the object is empty?

Comment: The two highest voted answers in the linked question should work perfectly for you.

Comment: `empty((array)($object))` as well.

Comment: @moonwave99 That will work in 5.5, but I don't think it will work in earlier versions, where `empty()` acts only on variables, not on expressions.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski [you're right](http://codepad.viper-7.com/stUlRe) ^^

Answer (score 0):

1. `if(empty($object)){
   }`

Or  :

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($object));
```

Using get_object_vars will return newProp, but the protected and private members will not be returned.

HelpLink [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: `empty()` actually doesn't work for this in PHP >= 5.0 "_Objects with no properties are no longer considered empty._" http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: so try with second one.